# The CSP frame-ancestors how to support Android Cordova apps

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, content-security-policy, iframe-app

I have added the CSP configurations `frame-ancestors: 'self'` on webserver https://www.exapleA.com/test/.

Currently I have another Android Cordova app and using iframe tag in JS file to loading above website pages, like as below:

```js
<iframe src="https://www.exapleA.com/test/"></iframe>
```

But I got the CSP errors like as below:

> Refused to display 'https://www.exapleA.com/test' in a frame because
>   an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "frame-ancestors 'self'

You know the Android Cordova apps added all the static files into the wrapper, so there no domain can append in "frame-ancstors". So how to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you are in control of the webserver: Remove `frame-ancestors: 'self'` again. As you pointed out the app does not have a domain name to add to your CSP.

Comment: but I can't remove the frame rules due to security.

Comment: If the ip address of the device running the app is static you could add the to the frame-ancestors, but otherwise I don't see a possibility to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

In your Cordova config (***config.xml***) you only have to add this:

```
<preference name="Hostname" value="custom-domain.co" />
<allow-navigation href="http://custom-domain.co/*"/>
```

Where ***custom-domain.co*** is like the domain of your Android APK.

Then, you will be able to config your website like so:

```
frame-ancestors: 'self' custom-domain.co
```

For more information see this link (section ***Configuration -> Hostname***): https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview

Comment: @albert could you please confirm if above solution worked for you or any other alternatives you tried?